# Websocket: there are 2 connections in chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, sveltekit

In chrome (*js* client), after connect to backend (*golang*) via websocket, I saw 2 connections in chrome devtools:

1. Frist connection, shows request url as: `ws://localhost:3000/`, and `3000` is the port of my frontend UI.
   messages:

   - a single `connected` message
   - a serial of `ping` message *(every 30 seconds)*.
2. Second connection, shows request url as `ws://localhost:18081/api/v1/..`, and `18081` is the port of my websocket backend.
   messages:

   - the read/write messages that client/server send to each other, by programmer.

**The questions are:**

- How many websocket connections are there between the js browser client & go server?
  I suppose there is only 1.
- If there is only 1, why chrome devtools shows it as 2 connections?
  Or, chrome just shows them separately for easier debug?

---

## Update (about the frontend framework)

The frontend uses `svelte-kit`, which in turn use `vite`, not sure does that matter?

Comment: Most likely you've got your webserver (not your websocket) running on a NodeJS server. Those usually run on port 3000 (socket.io). That's probably the front end connection you're seeing. As for the websocket, there should only be 1 connection between the browser and the websocket server. Just tested that with Chrome on my own websocket server and it only shows 1 connection.

Comment: I also suspect the WS connection to port 3000 is part of some development server, such as those bundled with webpack. In that case it facilitates things like live reloading and whatnot.

Comment: @icecub @Peter The frontend is using `svelte-kit` which in turn use `vite`, maybe that cause  the connection to `3000`?

Comment: @Peter The frontend uses `vite` which is similar as `webpack` I guess. So, you mean that connection to port `3000` is just another connection between ui & node backend, and has nothing to do with my backend `18081` ?

Comment: Couldn't directly find it in the docs, but yes, it seems `vite` uses a websocket connection going by this Github issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1925

Comment: Thanks both, just did a test, I opened the ui in chrome, then shutdown the go backend `18081`, the ws to `3000` is still connected, and continues to get `ping` msg, so yes that connection to `3000` is just to the local nodejs development server, not go server. Thanks.

Comment: And, after I stopped the frontend nodejs server, the `ping` from port `3000` is gone, which double confirmed the above conclusion.